# How to update java in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, updates

My Ubuntu 16.04 has the following:

```
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

Can you help me to understand how to update java version for "1.8.0_211" or latest?

Answer (score 0):

That's a very general question. For install see:

```
http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/07/31/install-oracle-java-8-9-ubuntu-16-04-linux-mint-18/
```

if it's already installed then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: I try this but I has next errors

E.g.:
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local
sudo cp jdk-11.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /var/cache/oracle-jdk11-installer-local/
sha256sum mismatch jdk-11.0.5_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 11 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java11-installer-local (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java11-installer-local
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)